# async event handlers in lit-html

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin, lit-html, kotlin-js

Is there a way to have `async` event handlers in lit-html ?

I have this submit event that's being triggered when the form is submitted to create a new user, but I also want to reload the list of users after a new user is added.

```
    constructor(container: Element, state: app.state.DashboardState) {
        this.container = container;
        this.state = state;

        this.state.usersCreateState.changed = () => render(html`
            <form
                @submit="${e => this.submit(e)}"
                class="stack display:flex flex-grow:1">
```

In order to do that, I need to `await` the usersCreate before I can refresh the user list.

```
    async submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(":focus")?.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"))
        await this.state.usersCreateState.create.submit()
        this.state.usersListState.list.submit()
    }
```

When making the `submit(e)` async, the submit event no longer triggers meaning the preventDefault doesn't trigger and instead, it tries to POST to the current URL while dumping this error in the console:

```
VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:20420 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at UsersCreate.submit (VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:20420)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:20408)
    at EventPart.handleEvent (VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:19355)
    at HTMLFormElement.EventPart.__boundHandleEvent (VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:19317)
submit @ VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:20420
(anonymous) @ VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:20408
handleEvent @ VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:19355
EventPart.__boundHandleEvent @ VM4535 user.ecff3a6d.js:19317
```

If I remove the async and await, this submit event triggers perfectly, except that the usersList reloads before or after the userCreate completed

The `...create.submit()` / `...list.submit()` methods are defined in Kotlin

```
    @JsName("submit")
    fun submit(): Promise<ResultVO> {
```

which generates TypeScript containing kotlin.js.Promise

```
submit(): kotlin.js.Promise<io.jvaas.state.vo.ResultVO>;
```

which is just a regular JavaScript Promise:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-promise/

Is there a way to get lit-html to correctly use the async event handler?

Alternatively, I could just do a callback, but the `async` / `await` just looks much better

```
    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelector(":focus")?.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"));
        this.state.usersCreateState.create.submit().then(() => {
            this.state.usersListState.list.submit();
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the event handlers. It looks like you're compiling to an old JS language version - at least pre ES2017 which added async functions (async/await) - and you're not loading the library (Regenerator Runtime) required to run the transformed async functions.

You need to load Regenerator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime

If you're using Babel to compile, this option might help: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#regenerator-aliasing

Comment: I'm using Parcel1, maybe I should try upgrading to Parcel2
( parceljs.org )